# Callback not correctly updating state (ReactJS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback

I have two components, of the same level under the parent component and depending on what happens in one, I want it to trigger something to happen in the other component.

I have a callback function in my Parent and I passed it to one of the Child. In the child, when an Icon is clicked, I call the callback function through `this.props.callback()` which goes back and triggers the function in the parent. But I keep getting an error when I'm trying to update the state so that when the parent re-renders, the other component displays differently.

**Parent:**

```
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            activeTab: undefined,
            messages: [],
            newMessage: undefined
        }
    },

    callback: function() {
        this.setState({
            "activeTab": "newChatTab"
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        const { activeTab, recentMessages, messages, newMessage } = this.state;

        return (

            <Modal>
                <div className="sms-chat-modal">
                    <ModalSC.Header>
                        <Icon name="commenting" color="white" />
                        SMS Chat
                        <Icon onClick={ this.handleClose } name="remove" color="white" float="right" />
                    </ModalSC.Header>
                    <ModalSC.Content>

                        <SMSChatLeftNav
                            recentMessages={ recentMessages }
                            callback={this.callback}
                        />

                        <div className="tabs-wrapper">

                            { activeTab == "newChatTab" ? <ChatTab messages={ messages } newMessage={ newMessage } /> : '' }

                        </div>
                    </ModalSC.Content>
                </div>
            </Modal>
       );
    }
```

**Child:**

```
render: function() {
    return(
        <FilterInput className= "search-field" placeholder="Search Recent Contacts">

            <Icon onClick={this.props.callback()} name="edit" color="blue" />

        </FilterInput>
    )
}
```

**Error:**

`Cannot update during an existing state transition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *invoking* the callback function when you write `this.props.callback()`. Just give the function to `onClick` on the `Icon` instead, so the function can be invoked when the event occurs.

```
<Icon onClick={this.props.callback} name="edit" color="blue" />
```

Comment: When I'm passing the callback function as a props to the child component, should it be `callback = {this.callback()}` or `callback = {this.callback}`

Comment: @Sam The second one. You don't want to invoke `this.callback` directly when you pass down the prop.

Comment: The problem now is that the icon doesn't trigger the callback. It doesn't seem to be doing anything anymore...

Comment: @Sam What happens if you bind the function to `this`? `<SMSChatLeftNav recentMessages={ recentMessages } callback={this.callback.bind(this)} />`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to destruct props by adding `callback` into `const { recentMessages, callback } = this.props;`. It works now!